# Trying to make a kind of pls dep all or pls dep max kind of thing

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a currency bot but I can't seem to figure out how to do something like: `[prefix] deposit all/[prefix] withdraw all` or `[prefix] deposit max/[prefix] withdraw max` but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. This is my code so far for deposit:

````py
@client.command()
async def dep(ctx, amount=0):
    users = await get_bank_data()
    user = ctx.author
    if amount > 0:
      users[str(user.id)]['wallet'] -= amount
      users[str(user.id)]['bank'] += amount

      with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

      await ctx.send(f"You have deposited {amount} coins!")

    elif amount < 0:
      await ctx.send(f"You can't deposit a negative amount of coins stupid!")

    elif amount == 0:
      await ctx.send(f"You can't deposit 0 coins stupid!")```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `in` keyword to check if the amount arg is either `max` or `all`, to check if it's a digit use `str.isdigit()`

```py
async def dep(ctx, amount: str):
    if amount.lower() in ["max", "all"]:
        # Deposit all the money here

    elif amount.isdigit() and int(amount) > 0:
        amount = int(amount) 
        # The `amount` variable is now a positive integer, deposit it here
```

You can do the withdraw command on the same basis